# List all API categories in Wikia API

Tags: api, categories, wikia

I am playing around with the Wikia API and have listed, for instance, all comics in the Marvel or DC Fandom Wikis, all the movies, etc.. using the following URL, where I substituted the relevant category.

https://dc.fandom.com/api/v1/Articles/List?expand=1&category=comics&namespaces=0&limit=10

Some of these categories are straightforward, so far I found movies, episodes, comics, novels, audio and characters. As far as I know, a complete list of all possible API categories is nowhere in the [documentation](https://dc.fandom.com/api/v1).

Is there a way to list all possible categories? For instance, I would like to list video games, but videogames or games is not a possible category. A list would make things considerably easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there is a [new endpoint](https://dc.fandom.com/api.php) for the Fandom API.

The MediaWiki query type you are looking for is [Allcategories](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allcategories). You will want to use the API parameters

- **action** = **query**
- **format** = **json**
- **formatversion** = **2**
- **list** = **allcategories**

You may also want to use

- **aclimit**=(maximum results returned, max 500 at a time, default 10)
- **acprop**=**size** (optional, show how many pages are in the category)
- **acfrom**=(name of the category to start from, like 'Category:Video Games')

Note that if you want to paginate through more than 500 results, you will need to also use the **accontinue** parameter returned in the first page of results in your next API query to get the second page of results.

[Here it is in action](https://dc.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&list=allcategories&acfrom=Video%20Games) on the DC Fandom.

If you already know the higher-level categories you're interest in, you may be interested in getting their subcategories using [categorymembers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers) instead. ([API query](https://dc.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Video%20Games&cmtype=subcat)). This is also the query you would use to get the pages that are members of those categories.